# With Django, can I reset primary key of all existing records?

Tags: python, django

Say I have a model `Client`:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = ...
    address = ...
```

And I imported a list of 1000+ clients to the model, with `django-import-export`.

It worked like a charm. However, the ids (primary key) of the records aren't start from 1.

It seems that by importing the clients, ids from 1 to 1000+ are used by `django-import-export`, and the imported client instances using id from 1000+.

No harm but not beautiful.

So is it possible to reset all the records' ids from 1?

Does `sqlsequencereset` work in this situation?

Comment: Auto incrementing IDs are rarely beautiful. It may be most productive to just accept that there may be gaps (even if you do successfully reset the sequence, gaps can occur again later)

Comment: Do you need these to allow referencing records (which will be imported similarly) correctly match these rows?

Comment: Consider the auto-increment id of your models as something internal that is only used to reference the correct row in the database. If you want an id that has a meaning for you, consider implementing an additional column and setting the value yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The ids are used to generate folders like "[1~100], [101~200],...". I think I have to be ok with some folders having many files and some having less files. As I said, no harm, but not beautiful. Thanks again.